# Can't open compressed file

Tags: c++, qt, zip

I'm trying to compress a text file with QT:

```
QFile inFile("d:\\build\\Directories\\Debug\\files\\developer.txt");
bool open_file_result = inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray ba = inFile.readAll();

QFile file("d:\\build\\Directories\\Debug\\files\\developer.gz");
bool open_zip_result = file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
out << qCompress(ba);

file.close();
```

`open_file_result` and `open_zip_result` are both `true`. I can also see the zip file (it also has a size, such as 50KB) but I can't open it. I'm getting the following error:

> The archive is either in unknown format or damaged.

What am I doing wrong? If you have a better/another way to compress a text file, please tell me!

Comment: I don't know anything about `QFile` specifically, but I do know Windows needs you to open such things in `binary` mode.  Is there a way to do that with `QFile`?

Comment: Probably `qCompress` just compress specified data and don't wrote the gz file header. You should open any of gz-file and check it's header for some `magic` data. And compare with yours generated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the Zip compression algorithm and the Zip container. You're confusing the two.

You need to do some research into the Zip container format that will help you locate and extract a zipped file within a Zip container. Once you've gotten that file, you can apply qUncompress to that file only.

Try looking at the [QuaZip](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/), which is a library that has been written for this purpose.